# how to dont trigger onclick eventlistner of parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

so I have a Post Container Witch Contain Post-body Title and buttons.

There Is Several Buttons(Like,Profile,Img). And I Dont Want To Trigger Parent Component Onclick Which Navigate User To Post Page

```
export default Post = () =>

return 
<div
      className={style}
      ref={postBody}
      onClick={(e) => {
        console.log(e.target)
        if (e.target !== postBody.current) { 
        // this just consider the post container div but some component like p which contain content
        // which in case of click navigation should happens
          handleNavigation();
        }
        //! dont let navigation happen if you click in other part of post (like)
      }}
    >
      <h2 className="text-stone-600 w-full text-center rounded-t-md ">
        {props.title}
      </h2>

      <p className="text-lg w-full text-center">{props.postText}</p>

      <div className=" flex justify-between  items-center w-full box-border ">
        <div className="flex justify-center items-center">
          <img src="" alt="" width={40} height={20} />
          <Link
            className=" text-lg text-stone-800 p-1"
            to={`/profile/${props.UserId}`}
          >
            {props.username}
          </Link>
        </div>

        {userAuthContext.authStatus && (
          <Like {...{ PostId: Postid, userAuthContext: userAuthContext }} />
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
```

I Tried To Control `e.target` And Compare It By Giving A `ref` To Parent Component And Control What Is Get Clicked And Decide Based On It,
but There Is Several Component Inside Post Container,
If I Click Them Like Div Which Contain Post Content ,
Other Thing Which Should Get Consider For Navigating To Post Page In Case Of Click,
but There Is Several Other Component In Case Of Click Should Not Trigger Post Container Onclick Navigation
So I Wanted To Know Is There Any Good Method To Dont Over Code It And Compare Every Thing.

Comment: info on event propagation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation

Comment: Please capitalize and punctuate your sentences so you're easier to read. This isn't a text message.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the below code in the onClick body will stop the container element from being triggered

```
event.stopPropagation();
```

Please see [Event.stopPropagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation)

Comment: Rather than just a link perhaps show code on how this can be used from what the OP provided.  Link only answers are discouraged and will likely get flagged